# How to jump to frame with flutter video player?

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

Is it possible to jump to certain timestamp and display the frame without starting the video using flutter video_player?

I was able to change a frame only when I call play immediately after seekTo.

```
  _videoPlayerController.seekTo(Duration(milliseconds: value));
  _videoPlayerController.play();
```

I also tried

```
_videoPlayerController.seekTo(Duration(milliseconds: value));
_videoPlayerController.play();
_videoPlayerController.pause();
```

but it does not change displayed frame of video.

Answer (score 0):

This answer probably comes a bit late, and is totally a hack
It shouldn't really be used, but it allowed me to have a similar behaviour

From what I could find, VideoPlayerController doesn't have any way to interact with the video regarding frames, only timestamps with the `seekTo` method you used. You just need to `play` and `pause` with a little delay in between actions and have it wrapped in an async function so that you can wait for the actions to complete, essentially this:

```
void moveOneFrameForward() async {
//Gets the current time point at where the video is at in a "Duration" type object
var currentTime = await _videoPlayerController.position;
//Seeks to the current time + an interval, in this case 100ms
await _videoPlayerController.seekTo(
Duration(milliseconds: currentTime!.inMilliseconds + 100),
);
//Plays the video so to render a frame
await _videoPlayerController.play();
//Delay so that the frame is rendered
await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
//Video is paused to display the frame
await _videoPlayerController.pause();
}
```